# Avoid merging/combining multiple feeds with Simplepie?

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

Here is my problem. I'm using Simplepie to fetch rss feeds. On the same page I'm trying to display two rss feeds (e.g. in two different columns). The two feeds are from the same domain (but I'm not seing that as a problem here, i.e. domain.com/feed1, domain.com/anotherfeed).

My problem is that Simplepie **keeps merging the feeds**. So in the first column I'm correctly seing the first feed, but the second column is a combined version of my two feeds - which is not the intention.

This is what I do:

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url($url1);
$feed->init();          
$rss = $feed->get_items();
$feed->__destruct(); // Do what PHP should be doing on it's own.
unset($feed); 

$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url($url2);
$feed->init();          
$rss = $feed->get_items();
$feed->__destruct(); // Do what PHP should be doing on it's own.
unset($feed);
```

The last two lines is an attempt to get rid of the first $feed instance, but nothing seems to be able avoid the merging of the two feeds in the second round.

At first, I thought this was related to caching issues, but disabling caching doesn't help.

Searching the community doesn't seem to give me any answers - so for some reason I'm alone with this problem. This tells my that I'm fundamentally missing something here? **Basically it would be nice to know how I can really kill the first feed, so it doesn't merge into the second?**

I really do hope that I've provided enough information for you guys to be able to answer. If not, then I'm sorry, and I'll do my best to update this question.

Answer (score 0):

Call your second feed something other than $feed, it shouldn't matter perhaps [on my homepage](http://www.muschamp.ca) I do this in the head:

```
<?php 
include_once './news/php/autoloader.php'; 
$muskblogFeed = new SimplePie();
$muskblogFeed->set_feed_url('http://blog.muschamp.ca/feed/');
$muskblogFeed->init();
$quotationFeed = new SimplePie();
$quotationFeed->set_feed_url('http://quotations.muschamp.ca/qotdFeed.php');
$quotationFeed->init();
$miniatureFeed = new SimplePie();
$miniatureFeed->set_feed_url('http://musksminiatures.wordpress.com/feed/');
$miniatureFeed->init();
?>
```

Then in the body to display the feeds I have this:

```
    <h3>My Quotation of the Day <a href="<?php print $quotationFeed->subscribe_url(); ?>"><img src="CommonImages/SocialMediaIcons/rss_16.png" class="rss16" /></a></h3>
    <?php foreach ($quotationFeed->get_items(0, 1) as $item): ?>
            <?php print('<blockquote id="quotation">' . $item->get_content() . '<br/><a href="' . $item->get_permalink() . '" style="float: right; padding-top: 2px; margin-top: 5px;">' . $item->get_title() . '</a></blockquote>'); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <br />
    <h3>Now on Muskblog <a href="<?php print $muskblogFeed->subscribe_url(); ?>"><img src="CommonImages/SocialMediaIcons/rss_16.png" class="rss16" /></a></h3>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($muskblogFeed->get_items(0, 3) as $item): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php print $item->get_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php print $item->get_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <h3>Now on Musk's Miniatures <a href="<?php print $miniatureFeed->subscribe_url(); ?>"><img src="CommonImages/SocialMediaIcons/rss_16.png" class="rss16" /></a></h3>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($miniatureFeed->get_items(0, 3) as $item): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php print $item->get_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php print $item->get_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

The above works fine, maybe you need do break up the work into head and body, I'm not a PHP guy, I don't even pretend to be one on Stack Overflow. Obviously variables have scope in PHP longer than just a single code block, but I'm never sure how long variables remain set. You seem to be in a hurry to unset() yours.